# Open and close fixed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a fixed div on the right of my page like this:

[image]

This is my html:

```
<a id="toggle" class="open"><img src="_styles/images/open_close.png" alt="openclose" /></a>
<div class="tweetdetails" style="width: 0px;">
  <p class="screenname">@BachelorGDM</p><br>
  <img src="linktoimage" alt="image_user"><br>
  <p class="createdon">Created on: Mar 8, 2013</p><br>
  <hr>
  <p class="text">Here is some text</p>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.tweetdetails{
  color:white;
  padding:10px 50px;
  position: fixed;
  right:0px;
  width:300px;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #FFF;
  height:100%;
  background-color: black;
      border-left: 5px solid rgb(127,255,255);
}

.open{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50px auto;
    color:red;
    position: fixed;
    right:400px;
    top:50%;
}
```

In my Javascript I have:

```
$("#toggle").click(function(){
    $(".tweetdetails").animate({width:'0px'}, 500);
    $("#toggle").animate({right: "-=300"}, 500);
})
```

But I always have an outcome like this:
[image]

How can I make sure I see nothing anymore? (I think it has something to do with the padding ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the fiddle if you're lazy ;) http://jsfiddle.net/tbleckert/UERHX/

That's because your padding will make the div 400px wide instead of 300px. You can add box-sizing to your div and add some extra width like this:

```
.tweetdetails {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 400px; // Since we added box-sizing
}
```

The box-sizing will make sure the div stays with the width you define. And then animate the toggle's right to -400px. Remeber to add vendor prefixes to box-sizing (-moz and -webkit).

But! The problem will still remain so I would suggest animating the right attribute instead of the width. And that will work.

I would suggest you put the #toggle inside the .tweetdetails and absolute position it outside. That way you will only have to make one animation as the #toggle will follow. Also you can do this with css transitions just by adding a class instead.

```
.tweetdetails {
  right: -400px;
  transition: 0.5s right; // Add vendor prefixes
}

.tweetdetails.open {
  right: 0;
}

$('#toggle').click(function () {
  $('.tweetdetails').toggleClass('open');
});
```

I've made a fiddle to show you what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/tbleckert/UERHX/

As a side note you shouldn't use ID's in your CSS but you should use them in your javascript. It's a good practise to add ID's to elements that you know you will use in your scripts (just don't go crazy, sometimes several elements applies and they should be classes so they can be looped easy).

Comment: Thanks man! You're the best! And how can I make sure it's already open when you load the page?

Comment: Hehe no problem! :) Just add the class __open__ by default to the div and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it more dynamic , without magic numbers:

```
 $(".tweetdetails").animate({width:'0px' , padding:'0px'}, 500);
 $("#toggle").animate({right: "-=" + ( $(".tweetdetails").outerWidth() ) }, 500);
```

`.outerWidth` is `width+padding+border` , have a look: http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

(Edited , thanks to @tbleckert)

Comment: That will only fix the toggle. The problem is that the div animates to 0px in width. The will go wrong since the div has padding.

Comment: That is still wrong...the tweetdetails has padding. Animating the width to 0px will still make it 100px wide.

Comment: No problem, I'm just here to help :)

Comment: And how can I open it again?

Comment: @niels123 in my opinion the easiest way is to rebind the click event handler

Comment: This is the problem with jQuery. They teaches you bad practices. One-liners all the way. Write more code and it will be easier to maintain and modify rather than "write less do more" as jQuery says. Look at my fiddle, the logic in an easy case like this could be in the CSS.

Comment: @niels123 i see that tbleckert gave more elegant answer , check out his jsfiddle link. i've upvoted him

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/XJbqD/

```
<a id="toggle" class="open"><img src="_styles/images/open_close.png" alt="openclose" /></a>

<div class="tweetdetails" style="width: 0px;">
    <p class="screenname">@BachelorGDM</p>
    <br/>
    <img src="linktoimage" alt="image_user"></img>
    <br/>
    <p class="createdon">Created on: Mar 8, 2013</p>
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <p class="text">Here is some text</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tweetdetails {
    color:white;
    position: fixed;
    right:0px;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height:100%;
    background-color: black;
    border-left: 5px solid rgb(127, 255, 255);
}
.open {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50px auto;
    color:red;
    position: fixed;
    right:5px;
    top:50%;
}
```

JS

```
$("#toggle").click(function () {
    if ($("#toggle").hasClass("opened")) {
        $(".tweetdetails").animate({
            width: '0px',
            padding: '0px'
        }, 500);
        $("#toggle").animate({
            right: "-=" + 400
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $(".tweetdetails").animate({
            width: '300px',
            padding: '10px 50px'
        }, 500);
        $("#toggle").animate({
            right: "+=" + 400
        }, 500);
    }
    $("#toggle").toggleClass("opened");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".tweetdetails").css('padding', '10px 0').animate({width:'0px'}, 500);
```

Comment: That will make the div jump 100px then animate. Not a very nice result in my opinion. That is also hard to maintain, if he wants to change the padding he will have to do that in both css in js.